# Initialize service on remote computer without LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy

Tags: windows, remote-access, windows-service, uac, pstools

I'm trying to use [PsTools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools) to configure remote computers. When I tried to initialize a Ps service at the remote computer for the first time, I got an `Access is denied.` error, even when authenticated as an administrator account.

Some websites recommend to change `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` to 1 in the registry, but when I did that, the authentication was not necessary anymore, and anyone connected to the network (with the same workgroup, probably) could initialize a service in the computer.

Is there any way to let services be initialized in a remote computer only with admin authentication without disabling User Account Control?

Comment: Turning off filtering should not give non-administrators any access they didn't already have, and certainly shouldn't give anonymous users administrative access.  You should double-check who is in the Administrators group on the remote computer(s).

Comment: So because I authenticated once, it means that I can access the computer without explicitly inserting the authentication info in the command?

Comment: Under some circumstances, Windows will remember the credentials you previously provided.  I'm not entirely sure of the details.

Comment: Oh... Ok I didn't know that. Thanks.